# How to set initial entry width in .Net MAUI?

Tags: .net, xaml, user-interface, controls, maui

I am developing an app which I would like to set an Entry control with an initial size on the width. Currently, despite I can write in the Entry control, this one is too small for a convenient UI.

So how to set initial entry control width in .Net MAUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MinimumWidthRequest` property of the Entry class in your xaml file.
For example:

```
<Entry x:Name="mainEntry"
       Placeholder="Write your input text here..."
       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
       MaxLength="255"
       MinimumWidthRequest="500"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find myself using grids and percentages more often than manually setting sizes. It makes the design respond well to different devices.

Also, good trick is to use margins, when you fill. If I do not know how wide I want something, I set left and right margins, it gets centered, and looks good on variety of screens.